# IPSec VPN using ZyWALL IPSec VPN Client: unable to connect from some providers

Tags: vpn, ipsec, isp, zywall

I'm trying to configure an IPSec VPN to one company from my home. The company has SANET internet service provider. I was able to create a VPN connection from another company that has the same internet service provider. The problem begins when I'm trying to connect from another ISP like Orange or Telekom. Here is the log from ZyWall:

```
20120816 10:06:18:359 Default (SA Gateway-P1) SEND phase 1 Main Mode  [SA] [VID] [VID] [VID] [VID] [VID]
20120816 10:06:18:375 Default (SA Gateway-P1) RECV phase 1 Main Mode  [SA] [VID] [VID] [VID] [VID] [VID] [VID] [VID] [VID]
20120816 10:06:18:390 Default (SA Gateway-P1) SEND phase 1 Main Mode  [KEY_EXCH] [NONCE] [NAT_D] [NAT_D]
20120816 10:06:18:718 Default (SA Gateway-P1) RECV phase 1 Main Mode  [KEY_EXCH] [NONCE] [NAT_D] [NAT_D]
20120816 10:06:18:734 Default (SA Gateway-P1) SEND phase 1 Main Mode  [HASH] [ID]
20120816 10:06:18:750 Default (SA Gateway-P1) RECV phase 1 Main Mode  [HASH] [ID]
20120816 10:06:18:750 Default phase 1 done: initiator id test@test.sk, responder id 111.112.113.114
20120816 10:06:18:765 Default (SA Gateway-Tunnel-P2) SEND phase 2 Quick Mode  [HASH] [SA] [KEY_EXCH] [NONCE] [ID] [ID]
20120816 10:06:18:953 Default (SA Gateway-Tunnel-P2) RECV phase 2 Quick Mode  [HASH] [SA] [KEY_EXCH] [NONCE] [ID] [ID]
20120816 10:06:18:953 Default (SA Gateway-Tunnel-P2) SEND phase 2 Quick Mode  [HASH]
20120816 10:06:48:968 Default (SA Gateway-P1) SEND Informational  [HASH] [NOTIFY] type DPD_R_U_THERE
20120816 10:06:48:984 Default (SA Gateway-P1) RECV Informational  [HASH] [NOTIFY] type DPD_R_U_THERE_ACK
```

ZyWall informs me that the tunnel was opened. But I can't ping or access any computer in the network.

```
My configuration at home: 
  ISP: Orange Optical connection
  Terminal: GPON OPTICAL NETWORK TERMINAL G-25E
  Router: TPLink TL-WR941N
        --> SPI Firewall Enabled
        --> VPN - IPSEC Passthrough Enabled
```

I was wondering if the problem could not be on ISP side (that he blocks somehow this connection because in SANET ISP it worked fine) or even in my terminal or router.

What could I check? Where could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

I had the same subnet on my local network(client side 192.168.1.X) and on the remote network(server side 192.168.1.X). So there was a little collision.